# How to close other active session on putty running on another computer?

Tags: linux, putty

I am trying to close a putty session that is running on some other computer.

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question? Or add more information to the question asked in your title.  Are you logged into a host that has multiple `ssh` login sessions open (e.g from `putty.exe` running on other machines)?

Comment: This may be a better question for the SuperUser system administration community.  OTOH if there are shell programming hacks it can go here too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You `kill` the process ID of the user's login session:

```
kill -9 12345
```

Try running the `w` command and looking at the output.  Something like:

```
w | grep ssh
```

will show all users connected via `ssh`.  More scripting and automation is possible to help you narrow down the process ID of the login session:

pgrep -u `w | grep ssh| awk '{print $1}'` ssh

will give you a list of numbers that are the `PID`s of the login session. You can then use `ps` to verify that this is the session you want to `kill`. See the `kill(1)`, `ps`, and `pgrep` manual pages.

You can get fancy and make a script or shell alias  to print the users and their ssh sessions (NB: quick hack for illustration, not portable):

```
for u in `w| grep ssh|awk '{print $1}'`
do 
  echo -e "\n"$u
  pgrep -x -l -u $u ssh
done
```

... and  other variation on this theme.  If you are killing sessions this way oftne it's a good idea to have a script or tool that helps you identify the correct session before your `kill -9` it - especially on a busy shell login host. Even more useful are tools that are cross platform and/or `POSIX`-ish (`w` `who` `ps` etc. vary slightly in their output formats).  That kind of tool can be written in `perl`, `ruby` or very careful `sh` and `awk`.